# Android Unit Testing Service (with Socket.IO connection) getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, socket.io, android-service

I am trying to do some `unit tests` with a `Service` that handles my `Socket.IO connection`, but I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the `Service` itself.

Under my `testPreconditions()` method, I am getting a `NPE` when using `getService()`.

**Why am I getting a NPE when trying to reference my Service class object?**

```
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.socketio.SocketIOClient;
import com.walintukai.lfdate.SocketIOService;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.test.ServiceTestCase;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.MediumTest;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;

public class SocketIOServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<SocketIOService> {

public SocketIOServiceTest() {
    super(SocketIOService.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}

/**
 * The name 'test preconditions' is a convention to signal that if this
 * test doesn't pass, the test case was not set up properly and it might
 * explain any and all failures in other tests.  This is not guaranteed
 * to run before other tests, as junit uses reflection to find the tests.
 */
@SmallTest  
public void testPreconditions() {
    assertNotNull("socketIOService is null", getService());
}

// Test basic startup/shutdown of Service
@SmallTest
public void testStartable() {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent();
    startIntent.setClass(getContext(), SocketIOService.class);
    startService(startIntent); 
}

// Test binding to service
@MediumTest
public void testBindable() {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent();
    startIntent.setClass(getContext(), SocketIOService.class);
    IBinder service = bindService(startIntent); 
}

@LargeTest
public void testConnectedToSocket() {
    SocketIOClient socket = getService().getSocketClientObj();
    assertNotNull("socket obj is null", socket);
    assertTrue("Not connected to socket", socket.isConnected());
}

}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
07-23 15:02:24.192: I/TestRunner(21725): finished: testBindable(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.192: I/TestRunner(21725): passed: testBindable(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.192: I/TestRunner(21725): started: testConnectedToSocket(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725): failed: testConnectedToSocket(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725): ----- begin exception -----
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest.testConnectedToSocket(SocketIOServiceTest.java:53)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725): ----- end exception -----
07-23 15:02:24.202: I/TestRunner(21725): finished: testConnectedToSocket(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725): started: testPreconditions(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725): failed: testPreconditions(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725): ----- begin exception -----
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: service is null
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:218)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest.testPreconditions(SocketIOServiceTest.java:32)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
07-23 15:02:24.212: I/TestRunner(21725): ----- end exception -----
07-23 15:02:24.222: I/TestRunner(21725): finished: testPreconditions(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.222: I/TestRunner(21725): started: testStartable(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.232: I/DB: Connection(21725): Opened
07-23 15:02:24.232: I/Socket.IO Service(21725): Stopped
07-23 15:02:24.232: I/TestRunner(21725): finished: testStartable(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.232: I/TestRunner(21725): passed: testStartable(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.232: I/TestRunner(21725): started: testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.242: I/TestRunner(21725): finished: testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.242: I/TestRunner(21725): passed: testServiceTestCaseSetUpProperly(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.242: I/TestRunner(21725): started: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.252: I/TestRunner(21725): finished: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
07-23 15:02:24.252: I/TestRunner(21725): passed: testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly(com.walintukai.lfdate.tests.SocketIOServiceTest)
```

Comment: What line for NPE? Give us the stacktrace and nobody gets hurt.

Comment: @CindyLangdon stacktrace added! please don't hurt anyone! and I'm sorry I misinterpreted the log. `assertNotNull("socketIOService is null", getService());` is throwing a `AssertionFailedError` so that means `getService()` is null.

Comment: Too late for that. ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documentations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html#getService()) says: `An instance of the service under test. This instance is created automatically when a test calls startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent).` So you must call `startService` or `bindService` before.